# VB.Net Writing to Txt File

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write the content of my textbox to a txt file.

My code works fine but my error is, when I open txt file I see

```
writeline1writeline2writeline3
```

instead of

```
writeline1
writeline2
writeline3
```

my code;

```
result As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
convertedText.Lines = result.ToArray()
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(mypath & "\convertedcontent.txt", convertedText.Text, False)
```

Writing to .csv and many other file types work fine but I don't know how to break lines for text file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: append `Environment.NewLine` to each line

Comment: You can use `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path,result.ToArray())`

Comment: Thank you Tim. This method worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`:

```
Dim path = System.IO.Path.Combine(mypath, "convertedcontent.txt")
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, result)
```

Otherwise you need to append `Environment.NewLine` to each line, you can use `String.Join`:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result))
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I guess I was using the wrong method. It was working fine for .csv, .xls, vs but I didn't have luck with txt files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `& vbCrLf` to your strings (each line)

Not sure where you are getting your strings from.. but you will have to add the carrier return/Line Feed character to those strings, one at the end of every string.

Might just even loop through your array and add them there?

P.S. Some of the comments have quicker ways of getting there, but this is probably what happens behind the scenes...

```
for i = 0 to convertedText.Lines.count -1
  convertedText.Lines(i) += vbCrLf
next
```

Comment: I've already tried adding new lines to the end of each line, but that is not the error. Textbox creates lines fine with or without adding new line command. But apparently convertedText.Text converts it back to 1 line.

Comment: I see... interesting. The the writelines as mentioned above should do the trick?

Comment: Yes, System.IO.File.WriteAllLines worked. I also tried adding ToArray, etc all possible options to My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText but did not work. It only supported .Text but it was messing up the lines. Thank you for taking your time and looking at it.